# Write an Sql query to display the top selling model of each manufacturer for each year

Tags: sql

Given below is the table of Car sales (of all models from different manufacturers) . ( only few rows are shown)

```
Date       Name    Model   Units_sold
Dec-2020    Audi    A4        300
Dec-2020    BMW     3Series   164
Jan-2020    Maruti  Alto      33118
Jan-2020    Toyota  Fortuner  1103
Feb-2020   skoda   Superb     391
```

Comment: tried this :select top 1 Model from Car sales order by Date desc;

Comment: what is your expected output ? that will be helpful

Comment: What is your actual SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Mysql is my database

Comment: SO isn't a homework completion service. You've posted your assignment, but not any effort to complete it yourself. Can you [edit] to include your own work, and explain what problems you're having with your SQL that attempts to do this?

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server we can try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Date, Name, Model, Units_sold
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Date), Name ORDER BY Units_sold DESC);
```